# how to show the selected item in java server pages

Tags: java, jsp

i have a code to showing the selected item, but it's not work

```
                <select class="form-control" name="grade">
                      <option value="X" <%if(rs.getString("grade")!=null){out.println('selected')}%>>X</option>
                      <option value="XI" <%if(rs.getString("grade")!=null){out.println('selected')}%>>XI</option>
                      <option value="XII" <%if(rs.getString("grade")!=null){out.println('selected')}%>>XII</option>
                    </select>
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrbZi.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
<option value="X" <%if(rs.getString("grade")!=null){%>"selected"<%}%>>X</option>
<option value="XI" <%if(rs.getString("grade")!=null){%>"selected"<%}%>>XI</option>
<option value="XII" <%if(rs.getString("grade")!=null){%>"selected"<%}%>>XII</option>
```